# Migrating from "jquery-ui-1.10.3" to "jquery-ui-1.11.0"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-migrate

> I have just started working on some old project which has used jquery-ui 1.10.3. Now i want to migrate to the latest version of jquery-ui i.e. "jquery-ui-1.11.0".
>
> But while migrating there are lot of confusion. Directory Structure of both are completely different.

**jquery-ui-1.10.3 Directory Structure**

[image: Directory Structure]

> **jquery-ui-1.11.0 Directory Structure**

[image: jquery-ui-1.11.0 Directory Structure e]

> So how to setup a production setup for **"jquery-ui-1.11.0"**. Is their any dependencies i need to take care while upgrading to new version.

Comment: are you sure your first directory structure is not your jQuery directory?

Comment: @DannyHearnah Yes, I am sure, I got zip from http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip location and extracted.